# what BrowserModule does in Angular2 application

Tags: angular

I have seen BrowserModule documentation but its not clear what it exactly does in Angular 2+ application. Can you point to any tutorial that clearly explains what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your on concept checking on these 2 references:

1) "the root module in the case of web applications imports the BrowserModule, which for example provides Browser specific renderers, and installs core directives like ngIf, ngFor, etc."

More info  available on:

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-ngmodule/

2) " The first thing that we notice is that our module is importing the BrowserModule as an explicit dependency. The BrowserModule is a built-in module that exports basic directives, pipes and services. Unlike previous versions of Angular, we have to explicitly import those dependencies to be able to use directives like *ngFor or *ngIf in our templates."

More info  available on:

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/introduction.html

3) We are not importing the BrowserModule but the CommonModule. If we see the documentation of the BrowserModule here, we can see that it's re-exporting the CommonModule with a lot of other services that helps with rendering an Angular application in the browser. These services are coupling our root module with a particular platform (the browser), but we want our feature modules to be platform independent. That's why we only import the CommonModule there, which only exports common directives and pipes.

> My question is that is it only for importing these common directives? Does it do any thing else like loading app in browser or related tasks?

As you commented on my answer I've updated it with this 3rd information that seems more accurate to your needs. More info here:

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/feature-modules.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. The latest i get update is that :"The BrowserModule is a built-in module that exports basic directives, pipes and services. Unlike previous versions of Angular, we have to explicitly import those dependencies to be able to use directives like *ngFor or *ngIf in our templates.". My question is that is it only for importing these common directives? Does it do any thing else like loading app in browser or related tasks?

Comment: I updated my answer if that is not enough maybe your are just searching for something like "lazy load" module in angular.

Answer (score 0):

It usually helps in bootstrapping in the angular 2 App

please see the link below

https://developer.telerik.com/topics/web-development/bootstrapping-browser-angular-2/